# Проблема с выводом массива (Задача по нахождению общих элементов массива)

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Задача: нужно найти общие элементы, которые содержатся в двух массивах одновременно.
На выходе программа должна выдать информацию вида: {a, b, c, ..., n}, где a, b, c, n - элементы массива. У меня получается лишь (если изпользовать тот код, что закомментирован) сделать вывод типа: {a, b, c, }, что является ошибкой, так как я сдаю лабы через сайт(progtest, если кто знает).

Поэтому я вижу новое решение: создаю еще один массив, в котором буду храниить одинаковые значения массивов первых двух. И если выводить значения массива в тот, момент, когда идет сохранение значений в массив, то все ок. Когда же я хочу вывести значения массива уже отдельным циклом, следующим после цикла нахождения элементов, то получается каша.

Пример:

arr1 = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

arr2 = 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9

вывод данных массива сразу после сохранения в него значений: 2, 3, 4

вывод данных массива в отдельном цикле: 5838432 2 3 4 83886085 4822

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size1, size2;
    int len1, len2;
    cout << "Enter size of set A:\n";
    cin >> size1;

    if (cin.fail() || size1 < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int arr1[size1];
    len1 = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(*arr1);
    cout << "Enter members of set A:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++)
        cin >> arr1[i];

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter size of set B:\n";
    cin >> size2;

    if (cin.fail() || size2 < 0)
    {
        cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int arr2[size2];
    len2 = sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(*arr2);
    cout << "Enter members of set B:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++)
        cin >> arr2[i];

    if (cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int* intersect = new int[len2];

    for (int i = 0; i < len1 ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < len2; j++)
        {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j])
            {
                //cout << arr1[i] << ", ";
                intersect[i] = arr1[i];
                cout << intersect[i] << " ";
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++)
    {
        cout << intersect[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если элементы дублируются, например, { 1, 1, 2 } и { 1, 1, 1 }, что должно быть выведено?

Comment: В таком случае должно быть выведено {1}

Comment: Если что - плюсы знаю плохо, поэтому буду искренне рад, если укажете на ошибки и скажетк, как исправить

Comment: Я не понял, а что у вас является ошибкой, как вы написали в сообщении?

Comment: Ошибкой является неправильный формат вывода. То есть сайт, на котором я сдаю эту лабу, пишет, что вывод неверный. Ну и конечно я не пойму, по какому правилу в массив заполняется этот "мусор"

Answer (score 1):

Ваша главная ошибка - в том, что вы присваиваете элементы пересечения не подряд:

```
intersect[i] = arr1[i];
```

Так что если, скажем, нулевой элемент в `arr1` не имеет такого же в `arr2`, в нулевом элементе `intersect` будет мусор.

Есть и другие. Я подправил ваш код, смотрите. Но учтите - *он не будет работать в случае, если множества на самом деле мультимножества, в которых могут быть повторяющиеся элементы*. Тут я исправлять ваш алгоритм не стал, просто предупреждаю о такой вот неприятности - подумайте сами, как быть с этим.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int size1, size2;
    cout << "Enter size of set A:\n";
    cin >> size1;
    if(cin.fail() || size1<0){
        cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int * arr1 = new int[size1];
    cout << "Enter members of set A:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        cin >> arr1[i];
    if(cin.fail()){
        cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Enter size of set B:\n";
    cin >> size2;
    if(cin.fail() || size2<0){
        cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int * arr2 = new int[size2];
    cout << "Enter members of set B:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i<size2; i++)
        cin >> arr2[i];
    if(cin.fail()){
        cout << "Invalid input.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    int ilen = (size1 < size2) ? size1 : size2;
    int *intersect = new int[ilen];
    ilen = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < size1 ; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < size2; j++){
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
                //cout << arr1[i] << ", ";
                intersect[ilen] = arr1[i];
                cout << intersect[ilen] << " ";
                ++ilen;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i< ilen; i++){
        cout << intersect[i] << " ";
    }

    delete[] arr1;
    delete[] arr2;
    delete[] intersect;
    return 0;
}
```