# Вложенные циклы javascript

Tags: javascript

помогите разобраться. Не соображу даже как правильно написать условия?

> Реализуйте и экспортируйте по умолчанию функцию, принимающую на вход два массива и возвращающую количество общих уникальных значений в обоих массивах.
> Для получения массива без повторяющихся элементов, используйте uniq из библиотеки lodash.
> В целях обучения и прокачки, решите это упражнение с помощью вложенных циклов.

Comment: Почитай про `lodash`-ный `uniq`... Посмотри примеры использования... Оно может и прояснится. Скажу больше - эту "задачку" (правда с модификациями) решают в сети по несколько раз за год! Стоит только загуглить. Она поди и тут есть уже решенная. ;)

Comment: Вот на `C++` https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591494/Проблема-с-выводом-массива-Задача-по-нахождению-общих-элементов-массива

Comment: Вот на `Java` - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1246156/В-отсортированных-массивах-найти-количество-совпадений-т-е-чисел-в-двух-массив

Comment: "В целях обучения и прокачки, решите это упражнение с помощью вложенных циклов" - я бы в целях прокачки сказал бы решить задачу без вложенных циклов :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"В целях обучения и прокачки, решите это упражнение с помощью вложенных циклов" - если бы не эта фраза я прошёл бы мимо :) Я, в целях прокачки, сказал бы решить задачу без вложенных циклов, т.к. с вложенными циклами (по-моему) очевидно

Могу предложить 2 способа решить это:

1. С помощью [набора](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) и счётчика:

   1. Создаём набор из уникальных элементов первого массива. Это позволяет нам не тратя время на поиски элемента и сразу узнать находится ли там искомый элемент или нет
   2. Если находится, то увеличиваем счётчик на 1 и в конце его возвращаем

   ```js
   const nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2];
   const nums2 = [4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 8];

   function countUniqElements(arr1, arr2) {
     let count = 0;
     const arr1UniqSet = new Set(_.uniq(arr1));
     const arr2Uniq = _.uniq(arr2);

     for (const el of arr2Uniq) {
       if (arr1UniqSet.has(el)) ++count;
     }

     return count;
   }

   console.log(countUniqElements(nums1, nums2));
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
   ```

1.1. Однострочный вариант первого способа ([reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))

```js
const nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2];
const nums2 = [4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 8];

function countUniqElements(arr1, arr2) {
  return _.uniq(arr2)
          .reduce(
            (data, el) => (data.count += data.arr1UniqSet.has(el), data),
            {arr1UniqSet: new Set(_.uniq(arr1)), count: 0}
          ).count;
}

console.log(countUniqElements(nums1, nums2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

2. Создаём набора и метода [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

   1. Создаём набор из уникальных элементов первого массива
   2. Во втором массиве оставляем только те элементы, которые находятся в наборе

   ```js
   const nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2];
   const nums2 = [4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 8];


   function countUniqElements(arr1, arr2) {
     const arr1UniqSet = new Set(_.uniq(arr1));
     const arr2Uniq = _.uniq(arr2);
     const uniqueInBothArr = arr2Uniq.filter(el => arr1UniqSet.has(el));

     return uniqueInBothArr.length;
   }

   console.log(countUniqElements(nums1, nums2));
   ```

   ```html
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
   ```

2.1. Почти однострочный вариант второго способа

```js
const nums1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2];
const nums2 = [4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 8];

function countUniqElements(arr1, arr2) {
  const arr1UniqSet = new Set(_.uniq(arr1));

  return _.uniq(arr2).filter(el => arr1UniqSet.has(el)).length;
}

console.log(countUniqElements(nums1, nums2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Благодарю за то, что не остались равнодушным и не прошли мимо. Такой вопрос: 1. В чём смысл `const arr1UniqSet = new Set(_.uniq(arr1));` ? Сколько в этом коде использовано циклов? 2. `for (const el of arr2Uniq) {
    if (arr1UniqSet.has(el)) ++count;
  }` Здесь точно нет вложенных циклов? 3. В однострочниках (написанных в функциональном стиле) например здесь `_.uniq(arr2).reduce((count, el) => count + arr1UniqSet.has(el), 0);` точно нет вложенных циклов? 4. Сколько Вы знаете способов перебрать элементы в последовательности кроме цикла, и рекурсии? Интересуюсь что-бы прокачаться.

Comment: @Andrei 1. Создаём набор из уникальных элементов (ссылку я оставлял можете почитать как оно работает). Зависит от того сколько циклов использовано в методе `lodash.uniq`, но сам `new Set` использует всего 1 цикл. Т.е. если написать `new Set([1, 2, 3, 4])`, то он за один проход создаст нужную структуру. 2. Там нет вложенных циклов. 3. Там точно нет вложенных циклов, все однострочники делают абсолютно ровно тоже самое что и не однострочные варианты. 4. "Перебрать" - это для меня всегда цикл :) А циклов у нас хоть отбавляй: `for`, `while`, `do while`, `for..in`, `for..of`, `forEach` и т.д.

Comment: Много в комментарии не напишешь из за их природы. Но по первому случаю объясню почему я задал первый вопрос. Что ссылку оставили это хорошо. Я о множествах читал, правда давно. Так вот, прочтите по этой ссылке о множестве, потом о uniq. И объясните зачем делать одно и тоже два раза `new Set(_.uniq(arr1));`? Если Вы сделаете вот так `new Set([1, 2, 3, 4,5,5,5]);` на выходе Вы получите коллекцию уникальных элементов {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. В тоже время если Вы сделаете вот так `_.uniq([1, 2, 3, 4,5,5,5]);` На выходе Вы получите коллекцию уникальных элементов [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

Comment: @Andrei Потому что по условию хотели, чтобы для получения уникальности было использовано `uniq`, но он возвращает мне массив, а мне нужен набор, потому записал это в `new Set`. Если можно не использовать `uniq`, то безусловно вы правы, можно просто воспользоваться `new Set`

Answer (score 0):

Примерно как-то так можно решить данную задачу:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 2];
const arr2 = [4, 6, 3, 2, 7, 4, 6, 1, 8];


function countUniqElements(arr1, arr2) {

  let count = 0;
  let temp1 = _.uniq(arr1);
  let temp2 = _.uniq(arr2);

  for (let i of temp1) {
    for (let j of temp2) {
      if (i === j) ++count;
    }
  }

  return count;
}

console.log(countUniqElements(arr1, arr2));


// export default countUniqElements;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: в чем смысл делать проверку `if (arr1.length > arr2.length) {`?

Comment: @Grundy Вы правы, исправил.